# ncurses.h Determining window borders

Tags: c, ncurses

I simply want to make a box window that borders around the terminal. All I'm basically asking is...

Say I have a window:

```
window(h,w,y,x);

y = LINES +1
x = COLS +1
```

How do I make it so that h and w are like `MAX_X -1` or `MAX_Y -1`

So that the box that I create outlines the terminal? and how would I fill this box with a certain color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `box()` function to draw a border around the edge of your window, you don't need to know the height and width to do it. Here's a simple example, with a white border on a blue background:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

#define MAIN_WIN_COLOR 1

int main(void) {

    /*  Create and initialize window  */

    WINDOW * win;
    if ( (win = initscr()) == NULL ) {
        fputs("Could not initialize screen.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Initialize colors  */

    if ( start_color() == ERR || !has_colors() || !can_change_color() ) {
        delwin(win);
        endwin();
        refresh();
        fputs("Could not use colors.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    init_pair(MAIN_WIN_COLOR, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
    wbkgd(win, COLOR_PAIR(MAIN_WIN_COLOR));


    /*  Draw box  */

    box(win, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(win);


    /*  Wait for keypress before ending  */

    getch();


    /*  Clean up and exit  */

    delwin(win);
    endwin();
    refresh();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you want to know the dimensions of the window anyway, you can use `ioctl()` like so:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

void get_term_size(unsigned short * height, unsigned short * width) {
    struct winsize ws = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    if ( ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) < 0 ) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *height = ws.ws_row;
    *width = ws.ws_col;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that this draws a border *in* the window, rather than outside it. This means that we have to make the window larger to accommodate the box, and then offset everything that we render inside the window's border. It would be nice if there was a simple way of drawing said box outside the window, but that would be mixing stdscr and window rendering...